# Can modules be hotpatched?

Tags: raku, hotpatching

I want to be able to hotpatch modules while the program is running for a project I'm working on. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
qx[rm -r .precomp/*];
try require PSBot;
try PSBot.test;
```

Is it possible to do? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Did you check what the error is when the `require` fails?  I bet that's an indication why that's going to be hard.

Comment: It returns no error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they can't. [CompUnits, compilation units or installed modules are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53737427/891440). [You cannot unload a module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53012231/891440) to load it again, which is what you mean by *hotfix*.

Comment: You can't unload, but could you potentially load again with a different version, and have a top level manager module that routed calls to the latest version?  You would eventually run into memory problems I guess.

Comment: Depending on if you want to keep any global state, I guess you could whip up a Perl 6 process that calls another process, which would drop out of that when needed.  But that feels more like you'd need an `nginx` frontend with a soft restart on the backend (if you catch my drift)